# Prevent combobox from being closed

Tags: c++, uwp, c++-cx

How to prevent combobox from being closed (when user will try to select some item, the combobox will not close): https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.ComboBox?view=winrt-19041

Comment: Can the following method help? Have you solved your issue?

Answer (score 1):

You can subscribe the DropDownClosed event, when the drop-down list closes, this event will be triggered, you can set the IsDropDownOpen as true to open the drop-down list. In addition, you can declare a property to judge whether the user selects item to cause this event to be triggered. For example:

.xaml:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="MyComboBox" DropDownClosed="MyComboBox_DropDownClosed">
    <ComboBoxItem Tapped="ComboBoxItem_Tapped">123</ComboBoxItem>
</ComboBox>
```

.h:

```
private:
    bool IsSelected;
```

.cpp:

```
void AppCX::MainPage::MyComboBox_DropDownClosed(Platform::Object^ sender, Platform::Object^ e)
{
    if (IsSelected == true) {
        MyComboBox->IsDropDownOpen = true;
    }
    IsSelected = false;
}


void AppCX::MainPage::ComboBoxItem_Tapped(Platform::Object^ sender, Windows::UI::Xaml::Input::TappedRoutedEventArgs^ e)
{
    IsSelected = true;
}
```